# XML schema namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm a beginner with xml and schemas. I'm going to be creating around 14 different xmls each with their own schemas (as I might have a few different people inputting information, want to make sure everything matches when I pull the data into the c# program i'm writing)
I've read through a few tutorials, and I get that the namespaces should be unique (usually)URLs.

Where I'm having issue (and some difficulty finding) is since, for now, none of this will be hosted on the web (the end program will come "packaged" with the xmls and xsds) does the namespace actually matter

more detail:

I'm using visual studios xml editor(because I'm a student, I got it for free, so I might as well use the damned thing)
It auto fills in some values with http://tempuri.org;

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
 xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

My specific question is, should I change the tempuri's or can I just leave them for now (eventually the friend I'm writing the program for does want it to be hosted on a website, but that's a long ways off as he wants a windows gui program first).

If it's recommended to be changed, does it matter what it's changed to? (yeah I'm a bit confused as you can tell)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order to take advantage of the schema while processing the employee element, the processor needs to locate the correct schema definition. How schema processors locate the schema definition for a particular namespace is not defined by the specification. Most processors, however, will allow you to load an in-memory cache of schemas that it will use while processing documents.

([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302086.aspx))

If you have another way to give your code that is processing the XML access to the schema in memory, your URL does not have to actually point to the location of the XSD.  If, however, you cannot provide the schema in memory some other way the URL should point to a valid location of the XSD.

Comment: well since I haven't yet started the programing, (i'm a student, and learning as I go) I'm not sure the in memory capabilities.

Could I use something like "C:\somefolder\whatever.xsd" and have that work for me

Comment: @Tyler W - what language(s) will you be using?

Comment: c# (sorry for the delayed response, been racking my brain on creating some schemas,lol).

Comment: @Tyler W - check out [this tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318504) on using XSDs in C#.Net